# Minimum of a random variable sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, bayes-theorem

$S_{n}$  model the price of a financial asset.

The recurrence relation is given by:
$$ S_{n+1} = (1 + r\Delta t_{n} + \Delta W_{n})S_{n}, n = 0, \dots, N $$

where $\Delta W$ has a normal distribution $\cal{N} (\mathrm{0},\Delta t)$

Let $\epsilon = P(S_{n+1}<0 | S_{n} = s)$ where $S_{n}$ are random variables.

I want to compute $P (\min_{1 \leq n \leq N}{S_{n}} \geq 0)$.

I proceed as follow:

$P (\min_{1 \leq n \leq N}{S_{n}} \geq 0) = P(S_{n} \geq 0 , \forall n=1,2,\dots, N) $.

Assuming that $S_{0} \geq 0$, we can say that $P(S_{1} \geq 0) = 1- \epsilon$.

For N=2,
$$P(S_{2} \geq 0, S_{1} \geq 0) = P(S_{2} \geq 0|S_{1} \geq 0) P(S_{1} \geq 0) = (1-\epsilon)^2$$

I was thinking if I could generalize this result so that, we have:
$$ P(S_{n} \geq 0 , \forall n=1,2,\dots, N) = (1-\epsilon)^N$$

Comment: In your definition of $\epsilon$ you have $S_n=s$. What is $s$?

Comment: $s$ is a positive number. Basically, $\epsilon$ is the probability that $S_{n+1}$ is negative given that $S_{n}$ is some positive number.

Comment: And that probability is the same for all $s$? Note that $P(S_1>0)=1-P(S_1\leq 0)$ and not $1-P(S_1<0)$ which it seems that you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. Yes, you can say that the probability is the same for all s.

Comment: Related (and probably making the present question obsolete): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/922285/